# How to filter or find properties based on attributes

Tags: .net, vb.net, reflection, properties, attributes

I have a class as follows

```
Public Class Foo
    Private _Name As String
    <ShowInDisplay()> _
    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return _Name
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Name = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _Age As String
    Public Property Age() As String
        Get
            Return _Age
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Age = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _ContactNumber As String
    <ShowInDisplay()> _
    Public Property ContactNumber() As String
        Get
            Return _ContactNumber
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _ContactNumber = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

I just need to work on only those properties which has a specific attribute eg:ShowInDisplay

```
Public Sub DisplayOnlyPublic(ByVal Someobject As Foo)
    For Each _Property As something In Someobject.Properties
        If _Property.HasAttribute("ShowInDisplay") Then  
           Console.WriteLine(_Property.Name & "=" & _Property.value)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: Updated with correct VB `GetType()` call:

```
If _Property.IsDefined(GetType(ShowInDisplayAttribute), True) Then
```

Comment: If _property.IsDefined(GetType(ShowInDisplay), True) Then

Thanks again

Comment: I am just trying to build a quick reference on reflection at  StackOverFlow for others . Thanks for participation

Answer (score 0):

With the exception of being able to make it nicer with extension methods / lambdas (in c# anyway), there is no simpler way than using MemberInfo.IsDefined on each of the available properties.