# Best way to associate or group properties within a class?

Tags: vb.net, object, properties

I'm new to creating objects, so I have question on the properties here. I'm creating a public class with a few sets of properties like the snippet below:

```
Public Class Template

    'General properties
Property ID As Integer
Property Name As String
Property Description As String
Property SupportedBrand As String

End class
```

Is there a way to "associate" properties with one another?  Say this group of properties is "general", these values are for "audio" and these for "video"? My inital reaction is to make a property that is a custom struct or list of these as enums but that doesn't seem to be right. Any suggestions?

I know that doing say Template.General.ID wouldn't be the right either since that is a separate module. My goal is being able to loop later to say "for each x property in generalProperties of this Template object".

Comment: those are not actually properties, but fields.  You want groups in what way? Are these on a control maybe?

Comment: I guess you're right, fields are more correct. I'm creating a custom object with said fields and I wanted to be able to group them together for both cleanness and the ability to loop just a certain section of the fields.

Comment: There are no Groups but there are objects like the many controls which contain inner collection (Items, Columns, Rows), but that is done by nesting classes.  There is a MP3 Tag reader that puts related prop groups in collections and it is a pain to fish out specific properties.

Comment: Ah okay. So I gander that grouping properties isn't recommenced?

Comment: If the app calls for, it do it, but `myFoo.General.FileSize` is just noisy.  Once case might be something like MediaInfo.DLL which coughs up media properties.  Codec and Format and the like exist for both Audio and Video, so "grouping" makes sense.  But since you are just reading prop vals, `myMedia.Audio("RunningTime")` (or similar) makes sense.  Thats not *quite* what you were asking.

Comment: That's alright. This was more of a "let's see if this is reasonably possible" question when you have an object with a long list of fields like I do. Good to know the options.

Answer (score 2):

You can add this attribute to your properties:

```
<Category("General")>
```

All properties with the same category name will be grouped together in the property window if grouping by category.  You can use reflection to get the attributes on the properties.  See this for an example on how to do that:

[How to filter or find properties based on attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531431/how-to-filter-or-find-properties-based-on-attributes)

Comment: that does not create a physical Group of properties though: `myObj.General.FileSize` is not magically created